# When two averages of (real) functions are given, when one function is equal to the average of the other?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose I have two real functions $f,g$ such that their averages over an interval are equal, i.e.$$\langle f\rangle = \langle g\rangle. $$ For simplicity, we can think that the average is over an angle and the average is over a full period $[0,2\pi)$. It is also the case that both functions depend on more variables aside from the averaged angle $\theta$, so that e.g. $\langle h \rangle$ is a function of the remaining variables.

My question is, when $$f=\langle g\rangle, $$ provided the above conditions are met?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, other than the trivial: when $f$ is $\langle g \rangle$.  Or, when $f$ does not depend on the variable you're averaging over.

Comment: As written, it's not clear what you're asking. In fact, you haven't even defined what kind of average you intend. Perhaps for $f(\theta, x_1, \dots, x_n)$, you want 
$$
\langle f \rangle (x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta, x_1, \dots, x_n) \, d\theta.
$$
Is this correct? Please edit your post to include more background information, including whatever definition you're working with.

Comment: Agh! It was a stupid confusion with some book notation. The integral was $\int_0^{2\pi} (h(z) - g )\frac{d\theta}{w} = 0$, where, in principle, $h,g,w$ all depend on $\theta$ (book's expressión). However, as the book is treating a perturbative expansion, in reality $h(z) =h(y)$ where $y$ does not depend on $\theta$.  If the average is defined as $\langle g\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} g\frac{d\theta}{w}/\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{w}$,then indeed $h = \langle g\rangle$.